# exception in launching cygwin in windows

Tags: windows, cygwin

I have installed cygwin on my windows 10 machine, but while launching getting following exception under file minttty.exe.stackdump:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=000FFFFC4AF
rax=00000000FFFFC4AF rbx=00000000008356F0 rcx=00000000008356FC
rdx=0000000000835868 rsi=0000000000836064 rdi=00000000FFFFC4AF
r8 =0000000000000004 r9 =0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000246 r12=0000000000000001 r13=00000000FFFFC4EC
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
rbp=0000000000000001 rsp=00000000FFFFC298
program=C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe, pid 7888, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
```

Right now launching C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe directly, for opening terminal

Comment: launching how ?

Comment: after installation, i got one shortcut on desktop, from that when i click a file gets created with name minttty.exe.stackdump where i am getting the above exception